# February 2013 Breaking Changes + Migration Pannel

Tags: facebook, migration

Why the February 2013 Breaking Changes, dose not appear on my migration panel? I have an alert on my app dashboard, that tells me that I should update my migration status but up to now I could not do it.  I believe this problem is messing with my app visibility because I could not find it on the Facebook search. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but according to this thread:
[Facebook February 2013 Breaking Changes - how to get rid of "fix now" message in App?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14820105/facebook-february-2013-breaking-changes-how-to-get-rid-of-fix-now-message-in)

... the issue is reported to facebook as a bug and that they are looking into it.

I hope this helps.